# lapply: producing several 3D scatter plots with different titles

Tags: r, plot, lapply

I'm trying to put the element name in the title of the graphic when running lapply. The problem is that the names are not iterating, just the first name is showed in all the plots.

Data example and code:

```
if(!require(scatterplot3d)) {
  install.packages("scatterplot3d"); require(scatterplot3d)}

head(palha_antes)
        X.mm Y.mm Altura.mm Rugosidade.mm
    1    0    0   198.421        24.677
    2   20    0   189.377        33.721
    3   40    0   199.212        23.886
    4   60    0   196.857        26.241
    5   80    0   193.048        30.050
    6  100    0   204.922        18.176

tratamentos = list(palha_antes, palha_depois, exposto_antes, exposto_depois)

names = c("Tratamento com palha antes da chuva",
          "Tratamento com palha depois da chuva",
          "Tratamento sem palha antes da chuva",
          "Tratamento sem palha depois da chuva")

names(tratamentos) <- names

par(mfrow = c(2,2))
lapply(tratamentos, function (x) {
  scatterplot3d(as.numeric(unlist(x[1])), as.numeric(unlist(x[2])),
                as.numeric(unlist(x[3])), xlab = "X (mm)",ylab = "Y (mm)",
                main = lapply(names(tratamentos), function(y) y), zlab = "Altura (mm)", pch = 20)
})
par(mfrow = c(1,1))
```

The part `main = lapply(names(tratamentos), function(y) y)` does not run as it should: [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pLaMU.png)

If I put x as function of y `main = lapply(names(tratamentos), function(y) x)`, the plot get all the values of the the variable x, not the name. So, do you have any suggestion to solve this part of the code? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why do you need 2 `lapply`? The following works.

```
tratamentos = list(palha_antes, palha_depois, exposto_antes, exposto_depois)

## don't use "names"; that will mask function "names"
NAMES <- c("Tratamento com palha antes da chuva",
           "Tratamento com palha depois da chuva",
           "Tratamento sem palha antes da chuva",
           "Tratamento sem palha depois da chuva")

par(mfrow = c(2,2))
lapply(1:length(tratamentos), function (i) {
  scatterplot3d(tratamentos[[i]][[1]], tratamentos[[i]][[2]],
                tratamentos[[i]][[3]], xlab = "X (mm)", ylab = "Y (mm)",
                main = NAMES[i], zlab = "Altura (mm)", pch = 20)
})
par(mfrow = c(1,1))
```

Essentially there is no need to use `lapply`. A `for` loop is perfect:

```
par(mfrow = c(2,2))
for (i in 1:length(tratamentos)) {
  scatterplot3d(tratamentos[[i]][[1]], tratamentos[[i]][[2]],
                tratamentos[[i]][[3]], xlab = "X (mm)", ylab = "Y (mm)",
                main = NAMES[i], zlab = "Altura (mm)", pch = 20)
  }
par(mfrow = c(1,1))
```

---

**Reproducible Example**

```
set.seed(0)
d <- data.frame(x = rnorm(50), y = rnorm(50), z = rnorm(50))
lst <- list(d, d, d, d)
NAMES <- LETTERS[1:4]

## `for` loop
par(mfrow = c(2,2))
for (i in 1:length(lst)) {
  scatterplot3d(lst[[i]][[1]], lst[[i]][[2]],
                lst[[i]][[3]], xlab = "X (mm)", ylab = "Y (mm)",
                main = NAMES[i], zlab = "Altura (mm)", pch = 20)
  }
par(mfrow = c(1,1))

## `lapply`
par(mfrow = c(2,2))
lapply(1:length(lst), function (i) {
  scatterplot3d(lst[[i]][[1]], lst[[i]][[2]],
                lst[[i]][[3]], xlab = "X (mm)", ylab = "Y (mm)",
                main = NAMES[i], zlab = "Altura (mm)", pch = 20)
})
par(mfrow = c(1,1))
```

Note, `scatterplot3d` has returned values, so if you use `lapply`, you will see a long list printed onto your screen.

[image]

---

**Comments on your code**

- You can use `x[[1]]` instead of `unlist(x[1])`; I also don't know what the extra `as.numeric` is for;
- `lapply(names(tratamentos), function(y) y)` is just `as.list(names(tratamentos))`.

Comment: Yesterday I was trying something like you and got a lot of issues, probably because my lack of experience with loops. Thank you Zheyuan.